# Camera software for Android with shutter mode, easy manual config, and video

Tags: android, camera

Is there a good camera for Android?

I have a Galaxy Note 4, but one thing I don't like about the default camera is that it has these image sharpening algorithms that make it look fake.

I just want a good camera that's easy to use and takes nice photos.

Ideal features:

- Shutter/burst mode (take photos in quick succession).
- Easy configuration (play with ISO, etc).
- Video mode.

Comment: Have you tried [Google Camera](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.google.android.GoogleCamera%26hl%3Den&ei=yWs3VafuApfq8AX42oGQDw&usg=AFQjCNGXIXOON9Y3ZtF56xvG-zSw0U7N2Q&sig2=G8loaM2N-PBqemdJu1wmvA&bvm=bv.91071109,d.dGc&cad=rja)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many [Camera Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera) meeting your criteria. I'd especially recommend you taking a look at …

### [A Better Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.almalence.opencam)

Almalence is known for high quality camera apps. *A Better Camera* is a "fusion" of several apps also available separate, and thus the features are plenty. They include a.o.

- HDR photos
- panoramas
- night mode
- Burst and Expo-bracketing
- **Multishot:** Group portrait, Sequence shot, Removing unwanted objects with one click
- **Video recording + pause**, incl. time lapse
- many, many more

(bold items are matching requirements you've listed). You can also **play with ISO**, aperture, and more. So this app would perfectly match your description. There are some minor restrictions: you can test all features, but some only a certain number of times (e.g. HDR). If you like the app and want those features permanently, you'll need to buy the [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.almalence.opencam_plus) for about USD 2. I did so, and it's still my favorite camera app – it had never let me down, results have always been amazing.

[image: ABetterCam] [image: ABetterCam] [image: ABetterCam]
<sup>*A Better Camera:* menu, panorama, viewer (source: [AndroidTapp](http://www.androidtapp.com/a-better-camera/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Then there's also …

### [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera)

Free and open source, good quality, nice to use. Hm, made by … Almalence (which explains its quality). Also meets your requirements: Video mode, ISO adjustments, and its "Auto-repeat mode" sounds like it would match your "Shutter mode". In addition, this one can use your <kbd>volume</kbd> keys for either zooming or shooting (maybe more – it has been a while that I've last checked it out). Plus an image stabilizer, which might come in handy in some situations.

[image: OpenCamera] [image: OpenCamera]
<sup>*Open Camera* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera); click images for larger variants)</sup>

With "easy to use" being one criterium, *Open Camera* will probably be a better match for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Camera ZOOM FX Premium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=slide.cameraZoom&hl=en):

- non-free
- Shutter mode (take photos in quick succession).
- Easy configuration (play with ISO, etc).
- Video mode
- tons of features
- can be used with any battery state (unlike the stock app, which can be used if the battery is below 5%)

[image]

Comment: I think you cannot record videos with it, you can?

Comment: @modiX I cannot remember but at the bottom right there seems to be a button to record video.

Comment: Oh I missed that, good to know.